# Failed to apply flutter plugin class 'flutterplugin'

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to flutter, and trying to run my first demo app and I get this error (Failed to apply flutter plugin class 'flutter plugin.). I am using Noxplayer as my emulator.
I have installed all needed plugins and made sure my flutter is up to date, I also used my `Command Prompt` to check for the issue using `flutter doctor` and `flutter doctor -v`, everything looks ok but it doesn't run on my emulator even though the emulator is connected to it.

```
C:\Users\Full Stack Dev\Desktop\Flut\first_app>flutter run
```

Launching lib\main.dart on SM G955N in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Full Stack Dev\Documents\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 190
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.
> No signature of method: java.lang.String.buildTypes() is applicable for argument types: (FlutterPlugin$_apply_closure7) values: [FlutterPlugin$_apply_closure7@4a7a23ba]

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 46s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            238.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1